# Do we really need -f flag in PHP mail? Why?

Tags: php, email

I've always included `-f` flag in my php applications because I thought it is important as the documentation told us:

> The user that the webserver runs as should be added as a trusted user
>   to the sendmail configuration to prevent a 'X-Warning' header from
>   being added to the message when the envelope sender (-f) is set using
>   this method. For sendmail users, this file is /etc/mail/trusted-users.

So it looks like it is used to prevent spoofing - by verifying who I am. Then I did a experiment. It turns out, if I do not include -f, there will still be no X-Warning when I send mails. In fact, the sender doesn't even need to be myself. For example, I tried `Obama@whitehouse.org` as sender, and I received the email with no warning. I even tried using `Obama@whitehouse.org` to send out a few hundreds of emails to multiple email accounts, and they didn't get flagged as spam.

So, my question is, what does `-f` flag really do (since it seems to me that without it, emails will send through just fine)?

Comment: "they didn't get flagged as spam" WhiteHouse.org (not the White House, by the way, that's .gov) doesn't have a SPF record, which is part of what lets you get away with that sometimes. You should use a real mailing class like SwiftMailer and stop worrying about sendmail flags.

Comment: @ceejayoz I see, so if I use WhiteHouse.gov which has a SPF record, I will be flagged without a -f flag? That's interesting. Thanks. Can you make it an answer?

Comment: You *might* be flagged. WhiteHouse.gov uses `~all` in their record, so it doesn't give the most useful info to email servers to flag your mail as spam. Spam filters work on lots of things, including content and the sending IP's reputation.

Comment: @ceejayoz You are right. I just tried `obama@whitehouse.gov` and it gets flagged as spam.

Comment: @ceejayoz and with -f flag the email does sent through!!! This is crazy. I am also going to look at swiftmailer now. :) If you make your comment an answer I will accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The -f flag is used to specify the `envelope sender` address.  You should use the -f flag to set this address so that it matches the `FROM` address in the headers of the message, otherwise some spam filters will be more likely to treat the message as spam due to the fact that the two do not match.

You can do something like the following to set both, so that they match:

```
$to = "to@to.com";
$from = "from@from.com";
$subject = "subject";
$message = "this is the message body";

$headers = "From: $from"; 
$ok = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f " . $from);
```

Comment: So leaving it empty is equal to setting it to match the `FROM` I assume? Because I tried leaving it empty when sending out `FROM: <Obama@whitehouse.org>`.

Comment: No.  Omitting the -f flag will most likely cause PHP to use whatever is set for `sendmail_from` in your php.ini for the envelope sender.  So, it would not match what you are setting for the `FROM:` address in the header.

Comment: Isn't this basically a bug in PHP that the `-f` flag isn't set the same as `From:` by default?

Comment: In SMTP, the `envelope sender` of a message and the `FROM address in the message headers` may not necessarily be the same.  So, this anomaly is not specific to PHP - or even the underlying MTA that PHP hands the message off to.  If anything, it's an anomaly of SMTP.  But, there are some legitimate reasons why the two may not match.  See http://serverfault.com/questions/518119/legitimate-reasons-smtp-mail-from-will-not-match-from-header-in-data.